# How to track the user browser url by using local vpn in android programmatically?

Tags: android, session, tcp, vpn, android-vpn-service

How to track the user browser url by using local vpn in android programmatically? I am using ToyShark local vpn code. By using this library i can capture the user browser action with in socket data worker.

```
private void writeTCP(Session session) {
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) session.getChannel();
    String name = PacketUtil.intToIPAddress(session.getDestIp()) + ":" + session.getDestPort() +
            "-" + PacketUtil.intToIPAddress(session.getSourceIp()) + ":" + session.getSourcePort();
    byte[] data = session.getSendingData();

    String s = new String(data);
    System.out.println(TAG+"writeTCP-----> " + s);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();

    try {
        channel.write(buffer);
        //Log.d(TAG,"finished writing data to: "+name);
    } catch (NotYetConnectedException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to write to unconnected socket: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error writing to server: " + e.getMessage());

        //close connection with vpn client
        byte[] rstData = TCPPacketFactory.createRstData(
                session.getLastIpHeader(), session.getLastTcpHeader(), 0);
        try {
            writer.write(rstData);
            SocketData socketData = SocketData.getInstance();
            socketData.addData(rstData);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //remove session
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to write to remote socket, aborting connection");
        session.setAbortingConnection(true);
    }
}
```

above write TCP method there is line

```
byte[] data = session.getSendingData();
String url = new String(data); 
System.out.println(TAG+"writeTCP-----> " + url);
```

by using the above writeTCP log i can track the user url, but the url result will be like

```
��������������������������www.videocond2h.com��������#����Ǹޮ̷�;�[+敊+�>M�N)Hi���o� S�j�.i��x������g�ν    �ShڄVO쨿k��4X�Oӷ>�-�kt:����|+�K�ƣ&�-b���*״%�o�=Y�O�Λ���.��ĊU���6~�ݓ����6f�xt=*Q�UQ��O}������������������������������h2http/1.1uP������������3��+��)::�������� ��k0b�E�x�Z������-�Q�o!�OT���v��-����+��
```

how can i get correct full url from below line of code . The url is **www.videocond2h.com**

```
 byte[] data = session.getSendingData();
```

---

Comment: **share me the code or referral link** is off-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can't track the URL in case of HTTPS connection, only the host. So what have you done so far? Starting from where you want help?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 you noticed that "close" button below the question, right ? We have a close vote reason for exactly what you mention, but I don't see your vote in there...

Comment: @2Dee: Oh looks like I missed that button ;)

Comment: i have edited the question above please check

Answer (score 0):

If you already have local vpn you can obtain info from tcp/udp `ByteBuffer`

```
        ByteBuffer packet_buffer = packet.backingBuffer;
        packet_buffer.mark();
        byte[] tmp_bytes = new byte[packet_buffer.remaining()];
        packet_buffer.get(tmp_bytes);
        packet_buffer.reset();
        Message message = new Message(tmp_bytes);
        Name query_domain = message.getQuestion().getName();
        String query_string = query_domain.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Here Message and Name class which class i have to import
android.app or android.os

Comment: @Karthik.N this is `org.xbill.DNS` from DNS Java http://www.dnsjava.org/doc/org/xbill/DNS/package-summary.html

Comment: Message message = new Message(tmp_bytes); in this line i got org.xbill.DNS.WireParseException:   @Stanislav